# Visualize CNN layer or pooling layer in tflearn

Tags: python, visualization, tflearn

Is there any way I can visualize the output of CNN or pooling layer while training or even testing in tflearn? I have seen visualization code of tensorflow but since session and feeddict are involved their and I keep getting error like "unhashable numpy.ndarray" but my dimensions of the image are same so I decided to ask whether there is a way I can visualize the output of any layer. Below is my tflearn layers code:-

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test=cross_validation.train_test_split(data,labels,test_size=0.1)

    tf.reset_default_graph()
    convnet=input_data(shape=[None,50,50,3],name='input')
    convnet=conv_2d(convnet,32,5,activation='relu')
    convnet=max_pool_2d(convnet,5)
    convnet=conv_2d(convnet,64,5,activation='relu')
    convnet=max_pool_2d(convnet,5)

    convnet=conv_2d(convnet,32,5,activation='relu')
    convnet=max_pool_2d(convnet,5)

    convnet=fully_connected(convnet,128,activation='relu')
    convnet=dropout(convnet,0.4)
    convnet=fully_connected(convnet,6,activation='softmax')
    convnet=regression(convnet,optimizer='adam',learning_rate=0.005,loss='categorical_crossentropy',name='MyClassifier')
    model=tflearn.DNN(convnet,tensorboard_dir='log',tensorboard_verbose=0)
    model.fit(X_train,y_train, n_epoch=20,validation_set=(X_test,y_test), snapshot_step=20,show_metric=True,run_id='MyClassifier')
    print("Saving the model")
    model.save('model.tflearn')
```

How can I visualize output from any layer either while training or testing anyway will work? By output I mean the distorted image detecting edges or other low level features. Thank you.

Comment: Is there a reason on why you can't set `tensorboard_verbose=3` and look at the layers' activations' histograms through tensorboard?

Comment: Sorry I dont really know about tensorboard_verbose=3 but is there anyway I can feed them to the plt or any other figure function and can get the distorted image that CNN uses to make predictions?

Comment: Okay I checked it out and even used it just to test the loaded model, it just showed the curves and all, Should I have to use it to train the model again to see the output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned [here](https://github.com/tflearn/tflearn/issues/194), you can see the output produced by an intermediate layer by simply defining a new model that has the observed layer as output.
First, declare your original model (but keep a reference to the intermediate layers you want to observe):

```py
convnet = input_data(shape=[None, 50, 50, 3], name='input')
convnet = conv_2d(convnet, 32, 5, activation='relu')
max_0 = max_pool_2d(convnet, 5)
convnet = conv_2d(max_0, 64, 5, activation='relu')
max_1 = max_pool_2d(convnet, 5)
...
convnet = regression(...)
model = tflearn.DNN(...)
model.fit(...)
```

Now just create a model to each layer and predict the input data:

```py
observed = [max_0, max_1, max_2]
observers = [tflearn.DNN(v, session=model.session) for v in observed]
outputs = [m.predict(X_test) for m in observers]
print([d.shape for d in outputs])
```

Which outputs the following evaluated tensors' shapes for your model:

> [(2, 10, 10, 32), (2, 2, 2, 64), (2, 1, 1, 32)]

With this, you will be able to look at the outputs during test. As for training, maybe you can use a callback?

```py
class PlottingCallback(tflearn.callbacks.Callback):
    def __init__(self, model, x,
                 layers_to_observe=(),
                 kernels=10,
                 inputs=1):
        self.model = model
        self.x = x
        self.kernels = kernels
        self.inputs = inputs
        self.observers = [tflearn.DNN(l) for l in layers_to_observe]

    def on_epoch_end(self, training_state):
        outputs = [o.predict(self.x) for o in self.observers]

        for i in range(self.inputs):
            plt.figure(frameon=False)
            plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.1, hspace=0.1)
            ix = 1
            for o in outputs:
                for kernel in range(self.kernels):
                    plt.subplot(len(outputs), self.kernels, ix)
                    plt.imshow(o[i, :, :, kernel])
                    plt.axis('off')
                    ix += 1
            plt.savefig('outputs-for-image:%i-at-epoch:%i.png'
                        % (i, training_state.epoch))

model.fit(X_train, y_train,
          ...
          callbacks=[PlottingCallback(model, X_test, (max_0, max_1, max_2))])
```

This will save images similar to this on your disk, at each epoch:

[image: Outputs for the first image in x_test, first epoch.]

Comment: Excellent explanation, just a silly question, when I have got the output shape of the tensor, how can I plot it and see. I can't do it on a simple matplot's plt function can you please help me there?

Comment: Also I get this error while doing callback thing for training "raise TypeError("'Tensor' object is not iterable.")" It is on this line "self.observers = [tflearn.DNN(l) for l in layers_to_observe]" I passed only max_0 as parameter.

Comment: You just need to pick one image and one kernel, and then plot it using `plt.imshow(output[image, :, :, kernel)`. Follow the code I wrote inside `PlottingCallback`. As for your error, it's because the callback is expecting a list of  layers to observe and you are only passing one. Notice that `(max_0)` is **not** a tuple of one element, but `(max_0,)` is.

Comment: Above mentioned error has been solved when I gave it another max_1 layer, now I am getting this error "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable" Somewhere in the callback function.

Comment: I need a little bit more information than that. Where exactly is this being raised?

Comment: "plt.figure(frameon=False)"....Then whole stack is like this...line 216, in fit line 352, in fit
caller.on_epoch_end(self.training_state)
"/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tflearn/helpers/trainer.py", line 352, in fit
"/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tflearn/callbacks.py", line 80, in on_epoch_end
caller.on_epoch_end(self.training_state)
callback.on_epoch_end(training_state)
"/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tflearn/callbacks.py", line 80, in on_epoch_end
"project3.py", line 41, in on_epoch_end
callback.on_epoch_end(training_state)
plt.figure(frameon=False)

Comment: That's odd because this is just regular matplotlib code. Run `pip install --upgrade matplotlib` and try to execute an example in matplotlib website (e.g. [plot_histogram](https://matplotlib.org/examples/frontpage/plot_histogram.html)) in a different script. If that works, then go back to your code and verify that `plt` really points out to `matplotlib.pyplot` and that you haven't modified the package in any way. If this doesn't work, just remove the `plt.figure(...)` call and add `plt.clf()` after `plt.savefig(...)`. This has pretty much the same effect.